# ListView Android Personalizado

Tags: android, listview

Estoy implementando un listview el cual ya lo tengo funcionando, pero necesito cambiar los datos que se visualizan. En la tabla de la base de datos que muestro, tengo 10 datos con un id foráneo, y 10 datos con otra id foráneo, y así sucesivamente, y lo que quiero es filtrar los datos que se muestre en el listview según el id foráneo que ingrese que en la aplicación , este paso es el que no se como implementarlo.

Aquí dejo el código del listview y adapter, y pantallazos de la app

```
public class ListarEstacionamientos extends AppCompatActivity{

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
ListView listaestacionamiento;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ProgressBar progressBar;
String idparkingholder;


private static final String REGISTER_URL ="http://www.app.transportessalgado.cl/listarcupos.php";
List<String > idLista=new ArrayList<>();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listar_estacionamientos);
    listaestacionamiento = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idlistview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.id_progressbar);

    new GetHttpResponse(ListarEstacionamientos.this).execute();
    idparkingholder=getIntent().getStringExtra("id_estacionamiento");
    //new GetHttpResponse(ListarEstacionamientos.this).execute();


    listaestacionamiento.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListarEstacionamientos.this, IngresoEstacionamientos.class);

            // Sending ListView clicked value using intent.
            intent.putExtra("valorLista", idLista.get(position).toString());


            startActivity(intent);

            //Finishing current activity after open next activity.
            finish();


        }
    });
}

// JSON parse class started from here.
private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Context context;

    String JSonResult;

    List<Cupos> cuposList;

    public GetHttpResponse(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {
        // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
        HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(REGISTER_URL);
        try
        {
            httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

            if(httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200)
            {
                JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                if(JSonResult != null)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                        JSONObject jsonObject;

                        Cupos cupos;

                       cuposList = new ArrayList<Cupos>();

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            cupos = new Cupos();

                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                            idLista.add(jsonObject.getString("id_cupo").toString());

                            //Adding Student Name.
                            cupos.cuposEstacionamiento = jsonObject.getString("id_cupo").toString();
                            cupos.estado=jsonObject.getString("estado").toString();

                            cuposList.add(cupos);

                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        listaestacionamiento.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(cuposList, context);

        listaestacionamiento.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menucerrarsesion, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

y aquí el adapter

```
public class ListAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
List<Cupos> valueList;

public ListAdapterClass(List<Cupos> listValue, Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.valueList = listValue;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return this.valueList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return this.valueList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewItem viewItem = null;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        viewItem = new ViewItem();

        LayoutInflater layoutInfiater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = layoutInfiater.inflate(R.layout.vista_listview, null);

        viewItem.TextViewCupos = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtcupos);
        viewItem.estadoCupos=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtestados);

        convertView.setTag(viewItem);
    }
    else
    {
        viewItem = (ViewItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewItem.TextViewCupos.setText(valueList.get(position).cuposEstacionamiento);
    viewItem.estadoCupos.setText(valueList.get(position).estado);

    return convertView;
}
}

class ViewItem
{
    TextView TextViewCupos;
    TextView estadoCupos;
}
```

y aquí los pantallazos de la aplicación
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí obtengo el id de estacionamiento y lo que quiero es que me muestre en el listview los datos asociados a ese id. alguna idea de como realizarlo por favor.

Comment: segun veo tu consultas los datos a un webservices, yo recomendaria que tu webservices reciba un parametro en este caso el id foreignkey y de acuerdo a eso webservice te devolvera los datos con ese filtro.
en php recibiria el id y le haria un select *from tabla  where idfk=$param. y eso retornarlo.

Comment: asi es, pero la duda que tengo es como implementar el envió del parámetro dentro de la aplicación, para que me muestre en el listview los datos asociados al id que envio. ademas ese id no siempre será el mismo.

Comment: en la variable idparkingholder recibo el id asociado a los datos que deseo filtrar desde la actividad anterior, pero no se como implementar el filtro, para que en el listview, me muestre solo los datos asociados a ese dato :(

Answer (score 0):

**Saludos!**

Debe de crear un Endpoint en tu servicio el cual reciba el parámetro del id foráneo y realize la búsqueda en tu DB.

Ejemplo:

```
// Opción 1
REGISTER_URL ="http://tudominio/listarcupos.php/3"
// Opción 2
REGISTER_URL ="http://tudominio/listarcupos.php?id=3"
```

**Nota:** 
Como cliente HTTP te recomiendo que dé un vistazo a [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Espero que te servia de ayuda

Comment: Pero ¿como va a filtrar los datos que se muestre en el listview según el id foráneo que ingrese que en la aplicación?

Comment: es como mencione anteriormente, el servidor web ya te daria los datos filtrados por ese id, tu solo tendrias que volver a crear el adapter con los datos recuperados en el json, en todo caso si tu recuperas todos los datos de tu web, podrias utilizar un **for** para recorrer la lista de todos los datos e ir agrupando en un List todos los datos que concuerden con el id seleccionado en un **if** o si es un objeto hacerlo con hashmap<Tipo objeto>

Comment: en la variable idparkingholder recibo el id asociado a los datos que deseo filtrar desde la actividad anterior, pero no se como implementar el filtro, para que en el listview, me muestre solo los datos asociados a ese dato :(

Answer (score 0):

Le estas enviando un string a tu intent

```
intent.putExtra("valorLista", idLista.get(position).toString());
```

intenta hacer esto

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ListarEstacionamientos.this,             
IngresoEstacionamientos.class);

// intenta enviarlo como objeto java
intent.putExtra("valorLista", idLista.get(position))

startActivity(intent);
```

despues puede obtenerlo en tu activity

Answer (score 0):

encontré una solución, la cual me filtra los datos según el id que se ingrese, dejo el código por si alguien tiene alguien problema similar.

```
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listar_estacionamientos);
    listaestacionamiento = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idlistview);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.id_progressbar);
    eleccionestacionamiento = findViewById(R.id.ideleccionestacionamiento);

    SharedPreferences guardarRut = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("guardarID", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userName = guardarRut.getString("ID", "");
    eleccionestacionamiento.setText(userName);

     String idestacionado=eleccionestacionamiento.getText().toString();

    new GetHttpResponse(ListarEstacionamientos.this, idestacionado).execute();





    listaestacionamiento.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListarEstacionamientos.this, EstadoReserva.class);

            // Sending ListView clicked value using intent.
            intent.putExtra("valorLista", idLista.get(position).toString());


            startActivity(intent);

            //Finishing current activity after open next activity.
            finish();


        }
    });
}

// JSON parse class started from here.
private class GetHttpResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public Context context;

    String JSonResult;
    String valorlista;
    String username;


    List<Cupos> cuposList;

    public GetHttpResponse(Context context, String idestacionado)
    //
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.valorlista = idestacionado;

        Log.d(TAG_MESSAGE, "onPostExecute: "+ idestacionado);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Passing HTTP URL to HttpServicesClass Class.
        HttpServicesClass httpServicesClass = new HttpServicesClass(REGISTER_URL);
        try {
            httpServicesClass.ExecutePostRequest();

            if (httpServicesClass.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                JSonResult = httpServicesClass.getResponse();

                if (JSonResult != null) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(JSonResult);

                        JSONObject jsonObject;

                        Cupos cupos;

                        cuposList = new ArrayList<Cupos>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            cupos = new Cupos();

                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Adding Student Id TO IdList Array.
                            idLista.add(jsonObject.getString("id_cupo").toString());
                            //idLista.add(jsonObject.getString("estacionamiento_id_estacionamiento").toString());

                            //Adding Student Name.
                            cupos.cuposEstacionamiento = jsonObject.getString("id_cupo").toString();
                            cupos.estado = jsonObject.getString("estado").toString();
                            cupos.id_estacionamiento = jsonObject.getString("estacionamiento_id_estacionamiento").toString();

                            cuposList.add(cupos);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, httpServicesClass.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listaestacionamiento.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArrayList<Cupos> filtrado = new ArrayList<>();


        for (Cupos s : cuposList) {
            //verificamos si el nombre del estudiatne contiene lo que se escribio en el editText
            if (s.id_estacionamiento.equals(valorlista)) {
                // es valido, lo agregamos a la lista
                filtrado.add(s);
            }
            Log.d(TAG_MESSAGE, "onPostExecute: "+ s);

            ListAdapterClass adapter = new ListAdapterClass(filtrado, context);

            listaestacionamiento.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }

}
```